# TabviewController - set TabItems in the middle

Tags: macos, swift3, nstabview

is it possible to center the tab view items of an NSTabController ?
At the moment they are on my left side:

[image]

but i would set theme into the middle.
i working with swift 3 for osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with `NSTabViewController`.

If you want to customize the tool bar, implement traditional `NSToolBar`